# How to properly use INNER JOIN in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I wrote the following query but I get a syntax error:

```
SELECT null as `null`, null as `null` FROM `e`.`detail_1year` T_1 WHERE (TRUE)
UNION ALL (select abc.address, 1 FROM T_1 INNER JOIN `e`.`detail_1year` abc on 1=1) LIMIT 1000
```

*AnalysisException: Syntax error in line 4:*

*...address, 1 FROM T_1 INNER JOIN `e`.`detail_1year` abc on 1=1)*

*Encountered: INNER Expected: FROM, LIMIT, ORDER, UNION, COMMA*

My Question:

Am I using INNER JOIN properly?

Comment: First: what do you want to do? what is your goal?. Improve your explanation giving some context of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You know `select abc.address, 1 FROM T_1 INNER JOIN e.detail_1year abc on 1=1` is a `CROSS JOIN` right? Most likely you don't need that..

Comment: I have some doubts about the validity of the query. The latter parts of a UNION need to have the same number and type of columns as the first part; putting _SELECT null as `null`, null as `null`_ first is probably causing issues.

Comment: Also, I am fairly certain you cannot reference an alias from on query of a UNION in another query of a UNION. As far as I know there is no such thing as "correlated unioning".

Comment: Thank you everyone, The error was in 1FROM

Answer (score 0):

in second line, if you want to select the field `e` from detail_1year (or abc), you will need this synatx:

```
select abc.address, 1,abc.`e` FROM T_1 INNER JOIN `detail_1year` abc on 1=1
```

Comment: That looks like a plain `CROSS JOIN` to me

Comment: Also, I think `e` could be a database name, not a column, so this: `e`.`detail_1year` could be of the form `database_name`.`table_name`.

Comment: e.detail_1year is the table name. I use `e`.`detail_1year` in the query because I have a mySQL db.

Comment: The correct syntax for inner join is a "Table Name" after join not a "Field Name". @AngelGarcia